# Where to dynamically change UILable size which is inside UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell subclass`, this cell subclass contains `UILabel`. Text will load from internet.

I want to resize this `UIlabel` according to text.

My `cell subclass UILabel` will only know the size when text arrives from internet, means I have to do resizing of `UILabel` when cell is drawing like this:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // resizing label here 
   cell.mylabel ...
    }
```

- Is there any other way to do the same or more efficient way to do the same?
- Can resizing can be done inside cell subclass?

Comment: You can do that. But is there a problem while doing that or are you just asking for best practice? If you are using autoLayout, then you can use constraints, but the size will have to be computed!

Answer (score 0):

When you update the text in the label in the cell you should call sizeToFit on your label to resize it:

```
[cell.myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Don't set the frame directly.

Personally, I would perform the sizeToFit on the UILabel inside the cell sub-class like so:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

then when the text on the cell is updated (which should happen inside cellForRowAtIndexPath), invoke `[cell setNeedsLayout]` which will force the `layoutSubviews` method to fire on the cell.

This approach makes for good separation of concerns and makes the Cocoa framework work for you in the way it is meant to.

If you are hoping the for UILabel to resize vertically as well as horizontally, you will need to set the numberOfLines property to 0 like so:

```
self.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a test to see which tableview delegate methods are called when the table is reloaded. I guess that as your waiting for the network to return your label details then the tableview will have already loaded in at least one time so you will after call [UITableView reloadData]; somewhere. Drop in a few log statements in the various delegate methods to see which is the best method for updating your label.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code to calculate the size of your label by its text. But you must assign label width or height firstly.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular" size:18], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle.copy};

CGRect cellSize = [yourText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(yourLabelWidth,9999) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
```

Comment: Where to do that in cellforrowatindexpath or inside cell subclass or any other efficient way? And thats what I asked in my question

Comment: You get the value of cellSize.size.height and put it in heightForRowAtIndexPath to return the cell height in your tableView.

Answer (score -1):

You should calculate your cell height just like [user2239950](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25702630/21052) said.

It seems your cell height computation is rather intensive and so I think the best place to calculate it is just when you receive your text from internet.

Beside the `NSString` that stores your text, you should add an `NSNumber` property that store the height once it has been calculated and re-use it each time you need it.

Comment: I didn't ask how to resize, I asked where to resize read my question.